# Does PHP 5.3.3 ignore my code or what?

Tags: php

i'm using a very simple code

```
<? if ($_GET["end"]=='1') { ?>
    <div id="header-message">
        this is the message
    </div>
<?  } ?>
```

in my company server the code is ignored and the browser displays the DIV

on my personal server the message is not displayed unless the variable $end is !=""

i'm having hard time what can cause this issue...is a difference in phph 5.3.3 vs 5.4?? or else? or may code is wrong??

Comment: Have you tried changing `<?` to `<?php`?

Comment: Is PHP enabled on the company server?  View the source of the generated page in the browser, if you still see `<?` in there, it's not being parsed.

Comment: Check your [`short_open_tag`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) setting.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, it is because you are missing the `php` portion of your php tag.

```
<? if ($_GET["end"]=='1') { ?>
    <div id="header-message">
        this is the message
    </div>
<?  } ?>
```

Becomes

```
<?php if ($_GET["end"]=='1') { ?>
    <div id="header-message">
        this is the message
    </div>
<?php  } ?>
```

**UPDATE**

As others have stated, the first option is valid if you have the [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) directive on.  Please also be aware that as of PHP 5.4.0, you do not need to specify the short_open_tag directive.

Comment: The first is acceptable syntax, but it requires `short_open_tag` to be on.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you.  I updated the answer with a link and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: if ($_GET["end"]==1) instead of '1'.. if your php.ini allows short tags his code should work with  too.

Maybe is read as integer in a case and as string in another.

Answer (score 0):

`1` means `true` but "1" is a `string` or `'1'`. So you use only `1` or `true` for check is true.

And use full tag `<?php ... ?>` instead short `<? ... ?>`